# TypeScript How to filter filter array of objects to single new object

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to filter this array of objects (`StopDetails`) and set a new object (`PickDetail`) to the object in the array that has the `TentativePickFlag = true`.

[image]

Comment: And? What problems are you encountering?

Comment: You can use the map function with an if: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: the problem is I have no idea how to do it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`const PickDetail = StopDetails.filter(detail => detail.TentativeNextPickFlag)[0];`

This the easiest way to filter the array to only show the desired items.